# Why do these custom fonts crash my Android application?

Tags: android

My Android application was running correctly in versions 2.1, 2.2 and up to 3.  The app crashes in 4.0 and 4.1 because of a custom font. How can this get resolved?

```
   Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvitica.ttf");       
   TextView customText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.splashtext1);
   customText1.setTypeface(font2);
```